# SAS MACRO pass vector parameter

Tags: sas

I have the following SAS macro code. But it seems do not work.

```
%macro test(covmatrix = );
proc iml;
 v = shape(&covmatrix, 5, 5);
 print v;
quit;
%mend;

%test(covmatrix={144, 95.04, 95.04, 95.04, 95.04, 95.04})
```

It will produce the error " All positional parameters must precede keyword parameters." Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

%test(covmatrix=({144, 95.04, 95.04, 95.04, 95.04, 95.04})) Works

Comment: Works because the extra set of parentheses hides the commas from the macro processor.  Another option would be to use the %STR() macro quoting function, which hides commas as well as other symbols:%test(covmatrix=%str({144, 95.04, 95.04, 95.04, 95.04, 95.04}))